# Spring JPA not storing to database

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

When I ran JUnit test on my service, it would successfully add the new entity to my database, but when I call the service from my Controller, it doesn't get saved to the database. What am I missing?

**jpa.xml**

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.mypackage.commons" />

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="showSql" value="true" />
    <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
    <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="jdbcDataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    <!-- spring based scanning for entity classes -->
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.mypackage" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" />

<tx:annotation-driven />
```

**UserService**

```
@Service
public class RepositoryUserService implements UserService {

    @Resource
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public User create(User user) {
        User newUser = userRepository.save(user);
        return newUser;
    }
}
```

**MyController**

```
@Controller
@Path("/users")
public class MyAPI {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @POST
    @Path("/add")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Transactional
    public Response addUser(User newUser) {
         userService.create(newUser);
    }
}
```

Comment: why `@Transactional` in the controller level ?

Comment: I think I saw it on some blog post, so tried it, hoping to fix my problem

Comment: I think @transactional should be only used in a service level, because you don't need persisted instances on your controller

Comment: But even without it, my entity was still not persisted in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the entityManager for Transaction :

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
```

and the annotation driven this way :

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"
    proxy-target-class="true" />
```

try to remove `@Transactional` from your controller, define Propagation and flush the session

```
  @Transactional(propagation= Propagation.REQUIRED)
    @Override
    public User create(User user) {
       try{
        return userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);
        } catch(DataIntegrityViolationException e){
         // handle the exception in here to find out what  is wrong            
        }
    }
```

Comment: I get `javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress` when I try `saveAndFlush`

Comment: Is there anyway to get this to work without proxy-target-class="true"?

Comment: yes you need to include `cglib` and configure jpa properties in your entityManagerFactoryBean

Comment: Do you have any links or suggestions on what I should look at?